# Splitting a string and converting to integer in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple problem but I started to use google bq and their help menu was so complex for me.

I have a column like that for some rows:

```
ANSWER(title of column)
9
10 - Certainly Satisfied.
7 -
```

My aim is to split the previous part of that column from "-" sign and convert it to integer. I found some formulas like split(), regexp_extract() but I couldn't be sure how can I imply them for my data.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number is always first, you can use:

```
select sum(safe.cast((split(answer, '-'))[ordinal(1)] as int64)
from t;
```

Note:  It looks like you have spaces, so you might really want to split on the space:

```
select sum(safe.cast((split(answer, ' '))[ordinal(1)] as int64)
from t;
```

Comment: I followed your approach, bq didn't let using index directly but with a small modification it worked: split(Q.ANSWER, ' ')[offset(0)]. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Consider below option

```
select answer, 
  safe_cast(regexp_extract(trim(answer), r'^\d+') as int64) as score
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]